# How do fix Arabic word turns into symbols?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am using Yii2 with php 8.0 and I try to insert values into the database using an excel sheet. when I tried to upload an Arabic word: `متلازمة داون`, it turn into: `&#1605;&#1578;&#1604;&#1575;&#1586;&#1605;&#1577; &#1583;&#1575;&#1608;&#1606;`, while inserting into Postgres. when using it in the select query it shows the same Arabic word. [image]

Comment: maybe, posting the result as image would help, even then how to you insert the values, have you the same charater set collation?...

Comment: the error shows only the symptoms, but not how your code is

Comment: Something converts your characters to HTML entities, and I don't think that is PHP or PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you should ensure that the encoding of your database is set to support Arabic characters. In Postgres, you can set the encoding of a database when you create it using the createdb command. For example, to create a database with UTF-8 encoding, you can use the following command:

```
createdb -E UTF8 mydatabase
```

You can also check the encoding of an existing database by connecting to it and running the following SQL query:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET encoding = 'UTF8';
```

Comment: database support Arabic. and Arabic words saved while using the form submit. the issue is only while insert using excel import